# django: forms - overriding time input widget

Tags: django, forms, widget

I overrided time input widget but when i submit that form, 'Enter a valid time' is shown

```
class TimePickerWidget(forms.TimeInput):                                                  
def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):                                                
    htmlString = u''                                                                      
    htmlString += u'<select name="%s">' % (name)                                          
    for i in range(12):                                                                   
            htmlString += ('<option value="%d:00 AM">%d:00 AM</option>' % (i,i))          
    htmlString +='</select>'                                                              
    return mark_safe(u''.join(htmlString))
```

as you see, it make drop-down box for time select. in form, it is called by

```
class JobForm (ModelForm):
   fromHour = forms.TimeField(widget=TimePickerWidget(format='%I:%M %p'))
   toHour = forms.TimeField(widget=TimePickerWidget(format='%I:%M %p'))
```

I have two questions.

1) When i submit, ' 'Enter a valid time' is shown. How can i solve this?

2) Is there any way to encapsule that format='%I:%M %p' format to the TimePicketWidget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `input_format` argument to [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#timefield), ie:

```
fromHour = forms.TimeField(input_format='%I:%M %p', widget=TimePickerWidget(format='%I:%M %p'))
```